# UnboundLocalError While Trying to Call a Function

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment that takes a number and tells the user if it is a valid SIN number. I can't get my program to run because of this:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'isdigit' referenced before assignment.

How do I fix this?

```
from sinmodule import is_valid

def main():
    print "SIN Validator"
    print "============="


   isdigit()

def isdigit():

    int_str = str(sinnumber)
    length = (len(int_str))        

    number = raw_input("Please Enter SIN (Q to quit):")

    while length != 8:
        print "You did not enter 'Q' or a number."
        sinnumber = raw_input("Please Enter SIN (Q to quit):")

    if length == 8:
        if status == True:
            print "The number",number," IS a valid SIN."
        else:
            print "The number",number,"is NOT a valid SIN."

    if number == "Q":
        print "Good-bye!"

main()
```

Comment: I hit a different problem. Your indentation of `isdigit()` on line 8 is wrong so the program doesn't run. If this call is really all the way to the left, the problem is that you call the function before you define it. If its inside `main`, then you are fine... but then you'll have problems with `sinnumber` which isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any issues with `UnboundLocalError` on `isdigit` in your code.  It is defined in one place, and called as a function inside of a second function.  The rules of scoping apply.

*However* you have not defined the variable `sinnumber` by the time you use it:

```
def isdigit():

    int_str = str(sinnumber)  # <--- here this is unbound
    length = (len(int_str))

    number = raw_input("Please Enter SIN (Q to quit):")

    while length != 8:
        print "You did not enter 'Q' or a number."
        sinnumber = raw_input("Please Enter SIN (Q to quit):") #<-defined here
    ...
```

You need to move the definition (in the while loop) to before you use it.  Also, check to see how you're "growing" `sinnumber`, and where you're updating `length`